# RegisterType with an interface in UnityContainer

Tags: c#, unity-container

I'm using UnityContainer, and I want to register an interface not with a type, but with another interface.
Unfortunately, I'm unable to do it cleanly..

I have several common interfaces, which are united in one interface, and I need to register them in the container. The code is like the following:

```
interface IDeviceImporter {
    void ImportFromDevice();
}

interface IFileImporter {
    void ImportFromFile();
}

interface IImporter : IDeviceImporter, IFileImporter {
}


class Importer1: IImporter {
}
class Importer2: IImporter {
}
```

When entering the library, I know which importer to use, so the code is like:

```
var container = new UnityContainer();
if (useFirstImport) {
    container.RegisterType<IImporter, Importer1>();
} else {
    container.RegisterType<IImporter, Importer2>();
}
```

and then I want to register this specific class with IDeviceImporter and IFileImporter also. I need something like:

```
container.RegisterType<IDeviceImporter, IImporter>();
```

But with that code I'm getting an error:  `IImporter is an interface and cannot be constructed`.

I can do it inside the condition, but then it'll be copy-paste. I can do

```
container.RegisterInstance<IDeviceImporter>(container.Resolve<IImporter>());
```

but it's really dirty.
Anyone please, advice me something :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm using ContainerControlledLifetimeManager, and end up with a code like:

```
var container = new UnityContainer();
System.Type importerType
if (useFirstImport) {
    importerType = GetType(Importer1);
} else {
    importerType = GetType(Importer2);
}

container.RegisterType(GetType(IImporter), importerType);
container.RegisterType(GetType(IDeviceImporter), importerType);
container.RegisterType(GetType(IFileImporter), importerType);
```

But yes, the best thing would be to have something like:

```
container.CreateSymLink<IDeviceImporter, IImporter>()
```

Answer (score 6):

Well this depends on the type of lifetime management you are using. Here:

```
  container.RegisterType<IImporter, Importer1>();
```

you use transient one, so you can do the following:

```
var container = new UnityContainer();

if (useFirstImport) {
    container.RegisterType<IImporter, Importer1>();
    container.RegisterType<IDeviceImporter, Importer1>();

} else {
    container.RegisterType<IImporter, Importer2>();
    container.RegisterType<IDeviceImporter, Importer2>();
}
```

without fear of bugs. `container.Resolve<IImporter>()` will create new instance on every call, just like `container.Resolve<IDeviceImporter>()` will.

But if you are using `ContainerControlledLifetimeManager` then anyway you'll have to use `container.RegisterInstance<IDeviceImporter>(container.Resolve<IImporter>())` because Unity offers no other way to do this.

This feature is really interesting, it would be very nice to have something like `container.CreateSymLink<IDeviceImporter, IImporter>()` but there is no such a thing.